# SH script fails when something already exists

Tags: shell-script, shell, openstack, rabbitmq

I have a problem with my SH script, I'm writing a SH script that automates the installation of OpenStack Keystone, and also uses a small configuration file, everything works fine but due to a syntax error on my part OpenStack command, script fails when something has already been created, example RabbitMQ user, Project or OpenStack User

The contents of my SH script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o xtrace

source "$PWD/install-keystone.conf"

conf=/etc/keystone/keystone.conf

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then 
  echo "To proceed with the installation of OpenStack Keystone you must be root user"
  echo "Please run as root"
  exit 1
fi


config_mysql()
{
apt install mariadb-server python3-pymysql -y


if ! test -f /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/99-openstack.cnf; then
cat >> /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/99-openstack.cnf << EOF
[mysqld]
bind-address = $HOST_IP

default-storage-engine = innodb
innodb_file_per_table = on
max_connections = 4096
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
EOF
fi

service mysql restart

}

config_rabbitmq()
{
apt install rabbitmq-server -y

 rabbitmqctl add_user openstack $RABBITMQ_PASSWORD

 rabbitmqctl set_permissions openstack ".*" ".*" ".*"

}

install_pkgs()
{
apt install keystone crudini python3-openstackclient -y
}

create_keystone_database()
{

mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS keystone"; 

mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$DATABASE_PASSWORD';"; 
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keystone.* TO 'keystone'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$DATABASE_PASSWORD';"; 

}

conf_keystone()
{

crudini --set $conf database connection mysql+pymysql://keystone:$DATABASE_PASSWORD@$HOST_IP/keystone
crudini --set $conf token provider fernet

su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone

keystone-manage fernet_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone
keystone-manage credential_setup --keystone-user keystone --keystone-group keystone

keystone-manage bootstrap --bootstrap-password $ADMIN_PASSWORD --bootstrap-admin-url http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-internal-url http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-public-url http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3/ --bootstrap-region-id RegionOne

service apache2 restart
}

create_projects_users()
{
 export OS_USERNAME=admin
 export OS_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
 export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
 export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
 export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
 export OS_AUTH_URL=http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3
 export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
  
 openstack project create --domain default --description "Service Project" service

 openstack project create --domain default --description "Demo Project" demo
 
 openstack user create --domain default --password $DEMO_PASSWORD demo
 
 openstack role create user
 
 openstack role add --project demo --user demo user

}

request_auth_token()
{

openstack --os-auth-url http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3 \
  --os-project-domain-name Default --os-user-domain-name Default \
  --os-project-name admin --os-username admin --os-password $ADMIN_PASSWORD admin token issue
  
  openstack --os-auth-url http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3 \
  --os-project-domain-name Default --os-user-domain-name Default \
  --os-project-name demo --os-username demo --os-password $DEMO_PASSWORD token issue

}

create_cli_environment_scripts()
{

if ! test -f /root/admin-openrc.sh; then
cat >> /root/admin-openrc.sh << EOF
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=2
EOF
fi

if ! test -f /root/demo-openrc.sh; then
cat >> /root/demo-openrc.sh << EOF
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=demo
export OS_USERNAME=demo
export OS_PASSWORD=$DEMO_PASSWORD
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://$HOST_IP:5000/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=2
EOF
fi

}

config_mysql
config_rabbitmq
install_pkgs
create_keystone_database
conf_keystone
create_projects_users
request_auth_token
create_cli_environment_scripts

echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "This is your host IP address: $HOST_IP"
echo "Keystone URL is available at http://$HOST_IP:5000/"
echo "The default users are: admin and demo"
echo "The password of administrator is '$ADMIN_PASSWORD'"
echo ""
echo "OpenStack Keystone has been successfully installed!"
echo "Learn more about Keystone in guides and more from : https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/"
echo ""
echo "Now connect this Keystone installation to other OpenStack services"
echo "It is recommended to subsequently install Glance (Image Service) on your controller node"
exit
```

My custom config file:

```
HOST_IP=
ADMIN_PASSWORD=
DEMO_PASSWORD=
DATABASE_PASSWORD=
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=
```

I realized that it initially failed because I made a mistake in the `--os-username` section I didn't enter the username and the script failed because of me

now as soon as it comes to OpenStack user creation on RabbitMQ it says the user already exists but the script fails without ignoring that message

Is there a way to ignore the message?

And I use `set -e`, to avoid having the script continue due to an error, but even if something exists it still marks it as an error and the script doesn't proceed

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this question is a duplicate, the question you sent me is useful to me!

Comment: If you want to rerun the script without modifications, you could delete the `openstack` user with `rabbitmqctl`.